# Outlook adding https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/ to hyperlinks

Tags: email, outlook

My email functionality in the current application has a feature that users can use to send document URL's to themselves for future reference or forward the email to known person, which can be used to access the website without needing to login, but recently it has been noticed that the hyperlinks are getting appended by https://na01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/ in the outlook email and its breaking the scope of the functionality in Chrome and Mozilla when user copy paste's the URL and try to use the hyperlink,It works only fine with IE browser. If I use the email feature and send it to lets say gmail account, the links are intact and works fine when an user clicks the link and it opens in chrome or mozilla. Please suggest how to make this work in outlook as that is the most common email editor that the end users are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I don't know how to disable the ATP / Safe Link feature - however, I notice that sending the email as HTML and not plain text will preserve the appearance of the hypertext (even though Outlook still changes the href attribute).

I'm using PHP native email.

First, I change the links - e.g.

```
$email_body = "<p>" . $message_text . "</p>";
$email_body .= "<a href=\"https://www.example.com\">www.example.com</a>";
```

Second, I set the headers - e.g.

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; format=flowed; charset=\"utf-8\"; reply-type=original\r\n";
$headers .= "From: =?utf-8?b?" . base64_encode( $from_name ) . "?= <" . $from_a . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: =?utf-8?b?" . base64_encode( $name ) . "?= <" . $email_address . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Third, I call native PHP mail();

The final result looks like a readable email (even though Outlook still changes href attributes).

For some, it is probably bit of an effort to convert emails from plain text to HTML - however, the benefit is that you have something more consistent looking across most email clients.